# Changing my primary email

Tags: facebook, email, yahoo

Here is my problem, at one point in the past i created another Facebook account to give me more credits in a Facebook game. I used my personal email that i currently use every day. Now i have deleted that Facebook account, my question is how do i use that email address that i used in a previous account and apply it to my account that i use now? The email accounts that i have provided Facebook i do not use.

Answer (score 6):

1. Login to Facebook with your old credentials
2. Go to account settings, click Edit in Email section
3. Add another e-mail (confirm with password)
4. Receive validation e-mail, click link they've sent you
5. Go back to Email settings, set your new email as primary

After you log out, next time you log in use the new e-mail. You can even remove the old e-mail from your profile.

Comment: Seems like after adding new e-mail it's possible to login using any of those email addresses.